# symfony call parent form constructor from child form

Tags: forms, symfony, constructor, query-builder

I have three forms in symfony, two being children forms of the third.
In the parent form I have the following :

```
    ->add('category', 'entity',array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:MarketPlace\ProductCategory',
            'query_builder'=>$this->QueryBuilder
        ))
```

in the child form as well as in the parent form I have

```
public function __construct($queryBuilder=null)
{
    $this->queryBuilder=$queryBuilder;
}
```

I'd like to pass the querybuilder to the parent so as to avoid repeating the field properties in each child. For instance :

```
public function __construct($queryBuilder=null)
{
    $this->queryBuilder=$queryBuilder;
     $this->getParent()->__construct($queryBuilder)
}
```

I want to pass a querybuilder when instanciating children and use this querybuilder in the parent form as shown above. How can I call the constructor of the parent form knowing the child form extends AbstractType and refer to the parent with the regular getParent method ?

The idea is I will pass different querybuilders to the children when instanciating them but keep the architecture of the field common across children (hence the fact I put it in the parent) -children will differ on other elements of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form field parents are something different than PHP extending parents. You can't do this. If you want to do this, you have to add options to the form type to set the query builder.

Comment: well I guess I have to stick to defining all the fields that require a constructor attribute in the children forms then... thanks!